# Remove whitespaces and line breaks from captured data with Php Dom Document

Tags: php, preg-replace, domdocument

I'm trying to capture home_impact and away_impact but when i extract the text its full of blank lineas, white spaces, break lines and such like this:

```
  David Luiz 
        35'






        36'

            De Gea
```

I've also tried by extract just the div id match_info but it generates just an array with one element and also it has a lot of line breaks. I've tried using preserveWhiteSpace and preg_replace but didn't work, any idea how to avoid that? Thanks.

Html:

```
   <div id="match_info">
                           <div class="direct_line">
            <div class="home_impact"><div class='player_name'>David Luiz </div></div>
                <div class="minute">35'</div>
                <div class="away_impact">
                </div>
        </div> 
               <div class="direct_line">
            <div class="home_impact"></div>
                <div class="minute">36'</div>
                <div class="away_impact">
                    <div class='player_name'>De Gea</div>
                </div>
        </div> 
                <div class="direct_line">
            <div class="home_impact"></div>
                <div class="minute">38'</div>
                <div class="away_impact">
                    <div class='player_name'>Ashley Cole</div>
                </div>
               <div class="home_impact"><div class='player_name'>Juan Mata</div>/div>
                <div class="minute">35'</div>
                <div class="away_impact">
                </div>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath ($doc);
$expresionHome="//div[@class='home_impact']";
$expresionAway="//div[@class='away_impact']";
$nodesHome = $xpath->evaluate($expresionHome);
$nodesAway = $xpath->evaluate($expresionAway);
for ($i=0;$i<$nodesHome->length;$i++)
{
echo $nodesHome->item($i)->nodeValue;
echo $nodesAway->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim()` will get rid of your white space; you could regex replace the white space between your player names with a non-whitespace character prior to this in order to preserve it, trim off all other white space, then put the single, desired spaces back, possibly:

```
echo str_replace("@WSW@", " ", trim(  preg_replace("\^.*([\w]{1,})( )([\w]{1,}).*$\","@WS@", $nodesHome->item($i)->nodeValue)));
```

But I've not tested it, the regex might need a little tweaking and could probably be optimized with PCRE codes .

### Update

Scratch that plan, I'd forgotten trim() will preserve single spaces. This is what you want:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$nodesHome->length;$i++) {
    echo trim($nodesHome->item($i)->nodeValue);
    echo trim($nodesAway->item($i)->nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, already noticed that a trim would do the work. Thanks for pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 10):

You can use DOMDocument only without any trimming of node content or using regular expressions. Consider following example, please pay attention to DOMDocument properties **preserveWhiteSpace** and **formatOutput** (if you want to pretty-print it)

```
// DOMDocument with unformatted content
$unformatteddocument= new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$unformatteddocument->load(PATH_OF_UNFORMATTED_XML);

$document = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$document->formatOutput = true;
$document->loadXML($unformatteddocument->saveXML());
$document->save(PATH_FOR_FORMATTED_XML);
```

Answer (score 7):

Normalizing whitespace in PHP wiht UTF-8 encoding which is how DOMDocument in PHP returns strings:

```
$normalized = preg_replace(['(\s+)u', '(^\s|\s$)u'], [' ', ''], $text);
```

That is first reducing whitespace occurences into a single space each and then trimming space at the beginning or end of the string.

Compare with [2.10 White Space Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space) from the XML standard.